# How to open new instance of disk usage analyzer/baobab

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage

This feels like a dumb question, but that's linux life for you.

I just can't for the life of me figure out how to reliably open up a 2nd/multiple instances of disk usage analyzer/baobab. It seems like an unusual application in this regard.

To try to open another instance I've tried:

- Context menu (right-click) application icon has virtually nothing in it. No option for new instance/window/tab/whatever.
- "super key" search selecting  sends focus to existing open instance
- cli `baobab` sends focus to existing open instance

Maybe this is a important design decision by the developers and only one instance is legal or something -- but I just want to compare 2 different du analyses (which doesn't seem like a crazy thing to want to do) and I don't quite actually understand why this application is non-standard in this regard.

*nb: I did figure out a hack some months ago to open a new instance using software installer, so I know that 2 instances can run simultaneously with no apparent ill effect, but I can't replicate this today and I'm actually curious to understand why this application seems to behave differently to the others in this regard, thus coming here.*

Comment: Just curious... why do you want/need to do that?

Comment: @heynnema I want to do this all the time for different reasons because baobab is awesome. Maybe I'm tidying multiple disks at the same time. Maybe to bisect difference between an old and newer disk/directory. Maybe to drill down in to multiple places at once. There are heaps of use cases. The point is this application behaves in a manner that's dirfferent to most other GUI application and I'm interested to know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally. Running at this again today managed to find a solution.

From question: "How to open multiple instances of a program in Linux"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553452/how-to-open-multiple-instances-of-a-program-in-linux/31092963#163567

No gui solution, but cli worked for me:

```
sudo nohup dbus-run-session baobab &
```

Still want to get to the bottom of why *this* application is different in this regard. Performance? Some other plumbing thing? Anyway.

---

Full informative quote:
From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31092963/163567

> Allowing only one instance is actually harder to implement, because
> the program needs to find and communicate with the instance already
> running. This is done via D-Bus. In order to prevent communication
> with the already started instance you can run the program in another
> D-Bus session:
>
> `nohup dbus-run-session audacious&`
>
> Note: nohup will keep the program running even if the terminal is to
> be closed.
>
> This method should also work for other programs which do not let the
> user choose between multiple instance vs. one instance.
>
> Beware that this might introduce bugs, if multiple instances are
> accessing the same configuration files.
>
> Tested with xfce 4.10.1 and dbus 1.8.16-1

Comment: You can edit your program shortcuts to include the prefixed `dbus-run-session` so that you don't have to open a command line for this. I don't think you'll get an answer to the "why" question here. It would be best to open an issue in baobab's issue tracker: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/baobab/-/issues My guess would be that it's just a personal preference to force one instance. Or maybe they use a programming framework which does this automatically. Or they have some awesome D-Bus features and with multiple instances you would have to decide with which of the open baobabs to talk to.

Comment: Well, this just shows `+ 3146093 suspended (tty output)  sudo nohup dbus-run-session baobab`, so I still have to `fg` to type in my password for sudo, and then it's still taken over my terminal...

Comment: Thank You for the answer and others for comments. When I first run it I couldn't type in the password because of trying to run in a "background" with `&` I suppose. I had to run it without it - in "foreground". And at the end I don't think `sudo` is required (but if You've run it with `sudo` once, it may not be able to run without it again as "nohup.out" may be only available to read or write by "root" - so `chown`, `chmod` or deletion of the file may be required I believe).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add to @Williams answer because I had the same problem as @Steven Lu did in the comments.
In order to start the 2nd instance I had to run it as:

```
sudo nohup dbis-run-session baobab
```

(No `&` at the end)
Then you can enter your password

It took what seemed like a really long time for the app to pop up, I had written it off as not working, so beware of that as well